# Which model is used when the method .predict is applied to a GridSearchCV object in sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I have a question with regards to the GridSearchCV object in sklearn in Python. Say that I use a simple Pipeline object with 2 elements in it: i) a MinMaxScaler() and ii) a KNN model i.e. in total

```
pipe = Pipeline([
    ('scaler', MinMaxScaler()),
    ('classifier', KNeighborsClassifier())
])
```

Now I use GridSearch on that for "K" i.e.

```
tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=3)
param_grid = {"classifier__n_neighbors": np.arange(1,51,1)}
grid_search=GridSearchCV(pipe, cv=tscv, n_jobs=-1, scoring='roc_auc', verbose=1, param_grid=param_grid)
grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

This means 3 splits are performed for each "K" and the best model is the one with the highest average of those three numbers. Now if I use the method .predict() on the object grid_search which model is then used? Is it one of the three models where the average was the highest (i.e. the best "K") and there the model with the highest score? So the model is only trained on a part of the data of variable X_train? Or is it trained on the whole X_train data for the best "K"?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ["**`GridSearchCV.predict(X)`:** Call predict on the estimator with the best found parameters. Only available if `refit=True` and the underlying estimator supports predict."](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.predict)

Comment: Thanks, seen this as well, but thats not the precise answer.

Comment: If you scroll up, you'll see "**refit: bool, str, or callable, default=True**
*Refit an estimator using the best found parameters on the whole dataset.*". In your own words, it is trained on the whole `X-train` data for the best `K`.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understood it!